# How to show views filters on a block or page

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with exposed filters to customers.

I want the exposed filters on a separate page/block and views result on a  separate page.

How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose exposed form in block to yes in views advanced settings, Then you can find your exposed form block in block listing page and can configure to any page or region

[image]